# How to split an array into unequal parts according to a condition in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, conditional-statements

I am trying to divide an array of numbers into smaller chunks if the next element in the array is larger than the ith element. Basically, I have the following array:

`a = [97, 122, 98, 111, 98, 111, 98, 101, 101, 103, 103, 104, 97, 107, 107, 108]`

and I want to get sub arrays of:

```
a1 = [97, 122]
a2 = [98, 111]
a3 = [98, 111]
a4 = [98, 101, 101, 103, 103, 104]
```

and so on....

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what conditions are you applying?

Comment: Guys, thank you so much, I am new here thank you for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is slightly different from @azro solution, but conceptually the same.
You make use of a tmp to accumulate the numbers until the `if` condition is valid, otherwise you append `tmp` to `result` and you initiate a new `tmp` with the current number in it.

```
a = [97, 122, 98, 111, 98, 111, 98, 101, 101, 103, 103, 104, 97, 107, 107, 108]

result = []
tmp = []
for i, n in enumerate(a):
    if i == 0 or n >= a[i-1]:
        tmp.append(n)
    else:
        result.append(tmp)
        tmp = [n]
result.append(tmp)

print(result)
[[97, 122], [98, 111], [98, 111], [98, 101, 101, 103, 103, 104], [97, 107, 107, 108]]
```

Comment: Can you please explain verbally or in pseudo code what the algorithm does? Specifically, I am not seeing where the code initiates a new tmp, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on the pairs `current, next` and on condition stop the current values or add into it

```
a = [97, 122, 98, 111, 98, 111, 98, 101, 101, 103, 103, 104, 97, 107, 107, 108]
result = []
values = [a[0]]
for current_v, next_v in zip(a, a[1:]):
    if next_v < current_v:
        result.append(values)
        values = [next_v]
    else:
        values.append(next_v)
result.append(values)
print(result)  # [[97, 122], [98, 111], [98, 111], [98, 101, 101, 103, 103, 104], [97, 107, 107, 108]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
        a = [97, 122, 98, 111, 98, 111, 98, 101, 101, 103, 103, 104, 97, 107, 107, 108]
        i, result = 0, []

        while i < len(a):
            row = [a[i]]
            j = i
            while j+1 < len(a) and a[j+1] >= a[j]:
                row.append(a[j+1])
                j += 1
            i = j + 1
            result.append(row)

        return result
```

You go through all the values once and it's clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.where and numpy.split to split your array. The advantage of using numpy is that you avoid explicit loops, making execution much faster (especially for large arrays).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([97, 122, 98, 111, 98, 111, 98, 101, 101, 103, 103, 104, 97, 107, 107, 108])

idx = np.where(a[:-1]>a[1:])[0]+1 # index
a1 = np.split(a,idx) # split

print(*a1)
```

Output :

```
[ 97 122] [ 98 111] [ 98 111] [ 98 101 101 103 103 104] [ 97 107 107 108]
```

Comment: I am new to python, can you explain what the code does? It seems like a simple yet elegant solution..

Comment: The idx line offsets the array by one and compares element i with element i+1 (generating an array of True/False elements). The np.where function selects only the index of elements where ith element is greater then the next one (condition is True). 

The a1 line uses np.split to break up array a into multiple arrays based the index.